# Default binding address for outgoing connections

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address, tcpclient

On a system with multiple local IP addresses, it is possible to specify the *"default"* interface binding address for outgoing connections process-wide (C#, dotnet executable)?

Meaning: if the already pre-existing code doesn't specify the explicit endpoint upon construction of `TcpClient`, it would get injected the one given in the *"new default"* setup (I guess there is a *"standard default"* assigned by the OS).

The desired point is to bind multiple instances of an existing service to different addresses without modification of every `TcpClient` creation (which might be harder for parts created by 3rd parties) in the whole codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out on OS level (`Linux`) via `nftables` which allows changing of outgoing IP address on various criteria (group id used for my use case) in the postrouting chain. So, something like this might help:

```
table inet my-service {
        chain eth0snat {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                oifname "eth0" meta skgid 1001 snat ip to 1.2.3.4
                oifname "eth0" meta skgid 1002 snat ip to 1.2.3.5
                oifname "eth0" meta skgid 1003 snat ip to 1.2.3.6
        }
}
```

Based on the group id, the process is running as, the address is assigned.